# 'Small' form factor available for LWC in Partner Developer org but not in Partner Professional org

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have two orgs created in the Environment Hub, both on AP15.

The 'Partner Developer' org actually lists 'small' as a valid factor in LWC (e.g. in Lightning Page Builder you can select 'phone'); the 'Partner Professional' org fails to deploy the managed package I created and the Page Builder does NOT have 'phone' as an option.

I can't find any setting where i would be able to switch that on? The Lightning experience on iPad is off on both of them.